# NeoBundle の vimproc を make したい

Tags: windows, vim

neobundle.vimでvimprocを管理したく、初回セットアップの後、NeoBundleUpdateするのですが、気がつくと下記のエラーメッセージが出てくるようになります。

> vimproc's DLL: "C:/Users/*me*/vimfiles/bundle/vimproc.vim/autoload/vimproc_
>   win64.dll" is not found.  Please read :help vimproc and make it.

実際、当該ファイルは存在しないので、makeに失敗しているようです。
ここからの問題判別方法を知りたいです。

vimrcのbundleは下記のように記述しています。

```
NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {
    \ 'build' : {
    \       'windows' : 'tools\\update-dll-mingw',
    \       'unix' : 'make -f make_unix.mak',
    \   },
    \ }
```

追記： 初回のmakeは意図通りに出来ており、その際のvimprocの動作に問題は無いように思えました。その状態でしばらく使い続けてNeoBundleUpdateを行うとアップデート中で行われるmakeが失敗するようになる、という状況です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update-dll-mingw.bat` の作者です。このバッチファイルは、内部的に `make_mingw32.mak` または、`make_mingw64.mak` を使ってDLLをビルドします。

WindowsではLinuxと異なり、ロードされているDLLを書き換えることが出来ません。従って、NeoBundleから自動でvimprocのDLLをビルドしようとしても普通は失敗してしまいます。しかし、ロードされているDLLのリネームは可能なため、一度DLLのビルドを試し、失敗した場合には古いDLLをリネームして、再度ビルドを行うというのがこのバッチファイルです。（経緯については、 https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim/issues/131 を参照してください。）

このバッチファイルを使う大前提として、MinGWにパスが通っており、`make_mingw*.mak`でDLLがビルドできることが必要です。次の手順で確認してみてください。

1. `mingw32-make -f make_mingw64.mak` または、`mingw32-make -f make_mingw32.mak` をコマンドプロンプト実行しDLLがビルドされることを確認する。
2. コマンドプロンプトの同じディレクトリから、`tool\update-dll-mingw.bat`を実行してDLLがビルドされることを確認する。

なお、`update-dll-mingw.bat`は32/64bitを自動判別しますが、判別に失敗するようであれば、`32`または`64`を引数として与えてください。例:

```
NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {
\ 'build' : {
\       'windows' : 'tools\\update-dll-mingw 32',
\       'unix' : 'make -f make_unix.mak',
\   },
\ }
```

Comment: 教えていただいた方法で検証を行いました。
コンパイラとして、適切でないバージョンのものを利用していたのが原因でした。自分の場合はx86_64-w64-mingw32を個別にインストールして解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

[こちらの記事](http://www.jonki.net/entry/20140406/1396773150)に

> VimShellを動かすにはVimProcのdllを入れる必要があります。これまでは自分で作る必要がありましたが、2012/12/13版からvimprocのdllがgVimに同梱されています。

とあります。

[KaoriYaさんのvim](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/)をお使いでしたら、回答したディレクトリの plugins\vimproc\autoload にvimproc_win64.dll が存在しますので、そちらを指定の位置にコピーされてみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

このwindowsのビルド用のパスが違っていませんか?
vimprocと同階層の`make_mingw32.mak`か`make_mingw64.mak`をビルドしないといけないようですが…。

https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim#windows

Comment: 初回のmakeはLayzieさんのおっしゃる、make_mingw64.makで行ったのですが、githubのNeoBundleの項に'tools\\update-dll-mingw'とあったので、そちらに切替えました。その辺に原因があるのでしょうか…。

Comment: 作者です。
tools/update-dll-mingw は make を自動で呼び出します。
tools/update-dll-mingw の実行に何か問題がある（おそらくエラーが発生している）のだと思われます。
一度該当コマンドをコマンドプロンプトで実行してみて、エラーがないか確認するべきです。